# How to read VCard file?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to read VCard file .

I use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17393/vCard-Reader-with-Lightweight-Approach) sample.

but when i use this solution for this file .

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:Gump;Forrest;;;
FN: Forrest Gump
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
PHOTO:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-111-555-1212
TEL;TYPE=home,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-404-555-1212
ADR;TYPE=work;LABEL="42 Plantation St.\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America"
 :;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
EMAIL:forrestgump@example.com
REV:20080424T195243Z
END:VCARD
```

don't find parametr of Email/Phone/Address.

for example i use this Regex for phone

```
   RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;
    regex = new Regex(@"(\n(?<strElement>(TEL)) (;*(?<strAttr>(HOME|WORK)))* (;(?<strType>(VOICE|CELL|PAGER|MSG|FAX)))*  (;(?<strPref>(PREF)))* (;[^:]*)*  (:(?<strValue>[^\n\r]*)))", options);
```

but value of strAttr,strType in empty.

How to set Regex for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this regex for Address:

```
   regex = new Regex(@"(?<strElement>(ADR)) (;(?<strAttr>[^\n\r]*))? (:(?<strPo>([^;]*)))  (;(?<strBlock>([^;]*)))  (;(?<strStreet>([^;]*)))  (;(?<strCity>([^;]*))) (;(?<strRegion>([^;]*))) (;(?<strPostcode>([^;]*)))(;(?<strNation>[^\n\r]*))", options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find an existing library instead of reinventing the wheel. [This for instance](http://www.thoughtproject.com/Libraries/vCard/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

What options do you use?

If you don't use `IgnorePatternWhitespace`, then the spaces in your expression are a problem.

Another problem is, you check for a `;` before "VOICE", but in your string there is a `,`

Do you really need all those `*` quantifiers? If you want to make something optional, it is better to use the `?` quantifier, it matches only 0 or 1 times.

Comment: Thanks, I want to grouped string for two (Type,Value). when i use this regex, i have ":tel:+1-404-555-1212" for strValue but strAttr is empty . I sould get "home,voice" for strAttr.